# Seasonally Adjusted Year-Over-Year Analysis

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I understand that comparing raw data year-over-year addresses seasonality. Is is acceptable to compare seasonally adjusted data year-over-year to identify a nonseasonal trend or movement in the data?

For example, say I have monthly data on the number of houses sold in Sacramento from 2011 to 2016. Say the data for December 2016 was just released, and I want to analyze December's home sale behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You will end up with a series of percent changes versus year ago (or differences - which is more appropriate will depend on whether your seasonality is additive or multiplicative).